# QR code rendering with ZXing.Net.Mobile in Xamarin.Forms app

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm trying to use [ZXing.Net.Mobile](https://components.xamarin.com/view/zxing.net.mobile) to display a QR code as an image.

I'm having difficulty getting the `byte[]` returned from `BarcodeWriter.Writer(...)` into an image for display.

i.e. this does not display an image

```
public class BarcodePage : ContentPage
{
    public BarcodePage()
    {
        Image image = new Image();

        image.Source = ImageSource.FromStream(() => 
        {
            var writer = new BarcodeWriter 
            {
                Format = BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE,
                Options = new EncodingOptions 
                {
                    Height = 200,
                    Width = 600
                }
            };

            var bitmapBytes = writer.Write ("Some text");
            return new MemoryStream(bitmapBytes);
        });

        Content = image;
    }
}
```

The `bitmapBytes` byte array looks like it has reasonable values in the debugger, how can I turn that into an image for display?

If I change the Image.Source assignment to:

```
image.Source = ImageSource.FromUri(new Uri("http://i.imgur.com/q0aIYvC.png"));
```

then it does correctly display the image, so I know the problem isn't with the Forms layout, etc.

*Workaround*

At the moment, I'm doing conversion to a MemoryStream in the native, e.g. in Android I have:

```
public class BuildQrCodes_Android : IBuildQrCodes
{
    public async Task<MemoryStream> ImageStreamForAsync(string text)
    {
        var writer = new BarcodeWriter 
            {
                Format = ZXing.BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE,
                Options = new EncodingOptions 
                    {
                        Height = 600,
                        Width = 600
                    }
            };

        var bitmap = writer.Write(text);

        var stream = new MemoryStream();
        await bitmap.CompressAsync(Bitmap.CompressFormat.Png, 100, stream);
        stream.Position = 0;

        return stream;
    }
}
```

and then over in the Xamarin Forms side, I have

```
IBuildQrCodes qrBuilder = /* Service lookup */
var stream = await qrBuilder.ImageStreamForAsync("the text to encode");
return ImageSource.FromStream(() => new MemoryStream(stream.ToArray()));
```

which is doing what I want, so it's an acceptable workaround.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what widget "Content" in your code represents, but assigning your "image" to a Form View's Image Class that is a member of your ContentPage should do the trick.

In XAML, you would create an Image within your ContentPage, i.e. like in one of the Form's [samples](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/blob/master/TabbedPageDemo/TabbedPageDemo/TabbedPageDemo/TabbedPageDemoPage.xaml).

Otherwise, dynamically create an Image class widget, add it your layout via [AddView for your ContentPage](http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/6029/how-to-create-ui-elements-dynamically).

Comment: That's just `ContentPage.Content` so assigning a ` Xamarin.Forms.Image. to that should work fine. I've added a bit more detail to the question to make it clear that the Forms setup code is working OK.